# The same value for X and Y in Attribute Table

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I want to extract X and Y coordinates of points from shp file - infc, and put  them to  corresponding columns in Attribute Table.
My code just give the same X and Y for all points in Attribute Table:

```
infc = 'samplepoints1.shp'
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(infc)
# Enter for loop for each feature/row
X = []
for row in rows:
    # Create the geometry object 'feat'
    feat = row.getValue(shapefieldname)
    pnt = feat.getPart()

    # Print x,y coordinates of current point
    print pnt.X, pnt.Y
    X.append(pnt.X)
del rows

rows1 = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(infc, ["X_coord", "Y_coord"])
count = 0
for i in rows1:

    arcpy.CalculateField_management(infc, "X_coord", pnt.X, "PYTHON_9.3") 
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(infc, "Y_coord", pnt.Y, "PYTHON_9.3") 
    rows1.updateRow(i)
    count +=1
del rows1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My code just give the same X and Y for all points in Attribute Table

This is because you are writing the last pnt.X and pnt.Y from your SearchCursor onto every row in your UpdateCursor.  In the SearchCursor it loops through all the rows and gets pnt.X and pnt.Y and then you remove the cursor, so it's remembered the last pnt.X and pnt.Y which are then used in the Update.

You don't need separate SearchCursor and UpdateCursor here - you can just get from your Shape field in the UpdateCursor and write it to your fields in the same process:

```
infc = 'samplepoints1.shp'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(infc, ['SHAPE@XY', 'X_coord','Y_coord']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        x, y = row[0] # Get the X and Y values from feature SHAPE
        row[1] = x   # Set X_coord to value of SHAPE X
        row[2] = y   # Set Y_coord to value of SHAPE Y
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Also, you don't need to use a `arcpy.CalculateField_management()` in an UpdateCursor - the UpdateCursor does the change in the field value in place of the Calculate Field (usually much much faster too).